# Rails turbo content missing after turbo response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbo

I'm always having the same problem with all of my views that have multiple records with turbo.

I have a list of `recipients`, each with its own partial:

```
<div class="card px-6 py-4 rounded-xl bg-white mb-4 shadow" id="recipient_stock_card_<%= recipient.id %>">
  <%= link_to select_stocks_recipient_path(id: recipient.id),
              data: { turbo_frame: "select_stocks_modal" } do %>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary text-black"><i class="icon icon-ui-22 text-2xl mr-2"></i> Asignar artículos a este destino</button>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Each partial has a button that will open a modal where the user selects stocks:

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag 'select_stocks_modal', id: "select_stocks_modal", target: "_top" do %>
  <%= render 'shared/grid_modal' do %>
    <%= form_with model: @recipient, url: add_stocks_recipient_path, local: false, data: { turbo_frame: "_top" } do |form| %>
      <section class="flex flex-wrap lg:flex-nowrap">
        <div class="p-8 w-full md:w-1/2 lg:2/3 flex-grow">
          <h1 class="font-bold mb-3">Selecciona los artículos y cantidades a enviar a este destino:</h1>
          <div class="grid grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-4 "> <!-- Adjust the number of columns as needed -->
            <% @stocks.each do |stock| %>
              <div class="stock-item flex flex-col mb-5 card bg-white p-3">
                <% if stock && stock.product && stock.product.product_images.attached? %>
                <%= image_tag(stock.product.product_images.first.variant(:thumb), class: " w-40 h-40 mx-auto shadow-xl rounded-3xl", alt: stock.product.name) %>
                <% end %>
                <div class="stock-details flex flex-col justify-between h-[140px] mt-5">
                  <p class="text-lg font-bold flex-grow"><%= stock.product.name.truncate(80) %></p>
                  <p class="text-md text-primary mb-4 font-bold">En stock: <%= stock.current_stock %></p>
                  <%= number_field_tag "selected_stocks[#{stock.id}]", nil, min: 0, max: stock.current_stock, class: 'quantity-input input', placeholder: 'Cantidad' %>
                </div>
              </div>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="actions w-full md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/3 bg-white rounded-xl p-8 sticky sticky-top top-0">
          <h2 class="text-xl mb-5">¿Cómo enviamos tus artículos?</h2>
          <select class="select select-bordered w-full mb-5"
                  data-controller="stocks"
                  data-action="change->stocks#toggleShippingMethod">
            <option value="items">Enviar artículos sueltos</option>
            <option value="packs">Enviar como packs</option>
          </select>
          <div id="itemsDiv" style="display: none;">
            Los artículos se enviarán sueltos.
          </div>

          <div id="packsDiv" style="display: none;">
            Montaremos packs con los artículos elegidos y se enviarán en packs.
          </div>
          <%= form.submit "Enviar estos productos", class: "btn btn-primary btn-large w-full mt-5" %>
        </div>
      </section>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Then, the controller on success will respond with Turbo:

```
  def add_stocks
    @user = current_user
    @recipient = Recipient.find(params[:id])
    @recipients = @user.recipients.where(stocks_assigned: false)
  
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      params[:selected_stocks].each do |stock_id, quantity|
        quantity = quantity.to_i
        next if quantity <= 0 
  
        stock = @user.user_stocks.find_by_id(stock_id)
        next unless stock
  
        @recipient.recipient_user_stocks.create!(user_stock_id: stock.id, quantity: quantity)
        stock_adjust(stock, quantity)
      end
  
      @recipient.update!(stocks_assigned: true)
    end
  
    respond_to do |format|
      format.turbo_stream do
        render turbo_stream: [
             turbo_stream.replace("recipient_stock_card_#{@recipient.id}",
             partial: "recipients/recipient_stock_card_success", locals: {recipient: @recipient}),
             turbo_stream.remove("select_stocks_modal")
          ]
      end
    end
    
  end
```

It works fine for the first record saved. But everytime I click on a second record after the turbo update, I get the error `'content missing'.`

¿Any idea why Turbo is failing once responded succesfully for the first record?

Thanks!

Comment: Your issue is likely `turbo_stream.remove("select_stocks_modal")`.  [`Turbo::Streams::TagBuilder#remove`](https://rubydoc.info/github/hotwired/turbo-rails/Turbo%2FStreams%2FTagBuilder:remove): *"Removes the `target` from the dom."*. You are removing the modal entirely, so subsequent button clicks cannot open the modal because it no longer exists.